# htaccess redirect querystring value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, querystring

I need to redirect

```
www.URL.it/directory_one/index.php?param_one=XXX&param_two=**YYY**
```

to

```
www.URL.it/newpage.php?param_three=**YYY**
```

I tried all I found online but the only things that works is redirect directory_one/index.php to newpage.php without parameters.

I tried this .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.URL.it/directory_one/index.php? [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(param_one=XXX&param_two=**YYY**)
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.URL.it/newpage.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```

only to see if somethings happens but not works

I tried also

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /directory_one/index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param_one=XXX&param_two=**YYY**
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.URL.it/test/index.php? [L,R=301]
```

but nothings happened

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `AllowOverride` set for the directory `.htaccess` resides in or Apache will ignore it.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param_one=XXX
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param_two=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/directory_one/index\.php$ http://www.URL.it/newpage.php?param_three=%1 [L,R]
```

If `param_two` really is to be `YYY`, use this as there is no need to use backreferences:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param_one=XXX
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param_two=YYY
RewriteRule ^/directory_one/index\.php$ http://www.URL.it/newpage.php?param_three=YYY [L,R]
```

If none of the above work, another rule might take precedence or you may have placed the rules in the wrong spot. You should debug the whole thing with

```
RewriteLog /path/to/file.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: it doesn't work...;-(
this is what I wrote:          
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} main_page=product_info
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/shop/index\.php$ http://www.url.it/schedafilm.php?id_film=%1 [L,R]

nothing happens.....
sorry but I can not indent the code properly

Comment: Try specifying the full url, `http://www.url.it/...`, in the RewriteRule line. I just tested this in Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu), it works like a charm.

Comment: I used the full url, the last line was:                
RewriteRule ^/shop/index\.php$ http://www.url.it/schedafilm.php?id_film=%1 [L,R]

Comment: i put the http but not appears

Comment: I'm using Apache/2.2.14 (Unix)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nothing happened? sounds like you need to set the allow override directive in the apache config.

Comment: I added the two lines that you've reported at the end of the file, I created a file called file.log and set the path from the root but also with http in front but does not write anything. I tried to change it to file.txt but does not write anyway.
I'm doing something wrong? I read online that I should add the server parameter SymLinksIfOwnerMatch, can it be?

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param_one=XXX
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param_two=.*YYY.*
rewriteRule (.*) www.URL.it/newpage.php?param_three=%{QUERY_STRING} param_two
```